Snowflake Tasks | Limitation on number of tasks
As per the documentation here:

A single task is limited to 100 predecessor tasks and 100 child tasks. In addition, a task graph is limited to a maximum of 1000 tasks total (including the root task) in either a resumed or suspended state.

Does this mean, we can not have more than 100 tasks in the depth of the DAG?
Or does this mean, we can not have 100 immediate children or immediate predecessor?
In my desired setup my root task may have upto 10 immediate Children(Si: 0<i<11). Then a children may have 40 immediate children(Sij: 0<i<11, 0<j<41) and then each such children may have 5 immediate children(Sijk: 0<i<11, 0<j<41, 0<k<6) .
Thus root may on an avg 999 children but not immediate one.

It means 100 immediate predecessor or child tasks.
The DAG itself can only have a maximum of 1000 tasks - but you can structure the DAG hierarchy however you want, as long as no node has more than 100 immediate child nodes or more than 100 immediate predecessor nodes

Is the answer justifiable? I mean is it somehow inferred in the documentation and I could not see it or is it common sense?

It’s not inferred, it’s explicitly stated in the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro#task-graphs
